# Having trouble compiling my first c++ program

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>

private int chessBoard[8][8];

void printBoard(int board[][])
{
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
        {
            if(board[i][j])
            {
                cout<<"Q ";
            }

            else
            {
                cout<<"* ";
            }
        }
    cout<<endl;
    }
}

//This method will check if any queens are in attacking position to the left of the test queen placement
bool checkSpot(int board[][],int row, int col)
{
    bool safe = true;
    //checks the current row for queens
    for(int i=0; i<col, i++)
    {   
        if(board[row][i])
        safe=false;
    {

    //checks the upper diag
    for( int i=row, int j=col; i>0 && j>0; i--, j--)
    {
        if(board[i][j])
        safe=false;
    }

    //checks lower diag
    for(int i = row, int j=col; i<8 && j>0; i--, j++)
    {
        if(board[i][j])
        safe=false;
    }

    if(safe)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

bool solve(int board[][], int testCol)
{
    bool solved = false;
    bool safe;
    if(testCol==8)
    {
        solved = true;
        return solved;
    }

    for(int i =0; i>8; i++)
    {
        // test if the tested column(testCol) and the row(i) are both safe for the queen to be placed at then we can move into placing said queen and more onto the next column for
        // more solutions in this same method recursivly
        safe = checkSpot(board, i, testCol);
        if(safe)
        {
            //place the queen
            board[i][col]=1;
            //recursion to go back through this method in the next column
            if(solve(board[][], testCol+1)
            {
                solved = true;
                printBoard(board)
                return solved;

            }

            else
            {
                //if the queen cannot be placed, we have to remove the previous queens and move them until a solution is found.
                board[i][testCol]=0;

        }
    }

}       

int main()
{


    solve(chessBoard, 0);
}
```

There errors i continue to get are as follows:

```
8queens.cpp:3:17: error: variable or field ‘printBoard’ declared void
 void printBoard(board[][])
                 ^
8queens.cpp:3:17: error: ‘board’ was not declared in this scope
8queens.cpp:3:23: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
 void printBoard(board[][])
                       ^
8queens.cpp:3:25: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
 void printBoard(board[][])
```

The logic of this was pretty simple(at least i hope it works well) but i cant even get past the compiler. Can I get a little guidance on this problem?

You were all a huge help, but sadly i found out that I can only use 1d arrays for this problem so I had to start from scratch. Again thank you all for the help, your advice will definitely help me in the future.

Comment: Remove the `private` from `private int chessBoard[8][8];`. The function call `solve(board[][], testCol+1)` is wrong because of the `[][]`. Remove them. Also, you're missing an ending `)` to the `if` statement on that same line. There are more problems than that however.

Comment: A loop such as `for (int i = 0; i > 8; i++)` is obviously wrong. This is not what is causing your compilation problems, but you should change it to `i < 8`.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and learn C++ the right way from the beginning. Instead of arrays, use vectors.

Comment: I wish i could use vectors, I understand them a lot better but i have a old fashion teacher that says that vectors are to easy so we need to learn how arrays work the hard way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are many errors in your code. Lets look at them.

First of all, remove that `private` from

```
private int chessBoard[8][8];
```

you need to use `private` only on the members of classes . So change it to

```
int chessBoard[8][8];
```

Next, in all your functions, you have something like

```
void printBoard(int board[][])
                            ^
                            here, it's wrong
```

You need to provide the size, you can only skip the first size, all the rest must be provided so better to change it to

```
void printBoard(int board[][8])
                          ^
                          it's okay to leave this one
```

make that change to all of your functions.

You are also missing a few `}` in some places of your code.

Nearly forgot, you need to either add a

```
using namespace std;
```

right after the headers, or use

```
std::cin
std::cout
```

and

```
std::endl
```

instead of `cin` , `cout` and `endl` .

You also have

```
for(int i=0; i<col, i++)
                  ^
                  you need a semicolon here
```

And also

```
for( int i=row, int j=col; i>0 && j>0; i--, j--)
                 ^
                no need for another int here
```

just change that to

```
for( int i=row, j=col; i>0 && j>0; i--, j--)
```

Answer (score 0):

This compiles. As to what I did, there was a lot and it would take awhile to write each thing down. One major thing to pay attention to is the `for loops`.
You have:

```
for( int i=row, int j=col; i>0 && j>0; i--, j--)
{
    if(board[i][j])
      safe=false;
}
```

When you want to do a nested `for loop`, do this:

```
for (int i = row;  i > 0; i--)
{
     for (int j = col; j > 0; j--)
     {
          if (board[i][j])
             safe = false;
     }
}
```

Also, pay attention to your brackets `{} ()` as they were inconsistent and some were missing.

For arrays, you must specify at least one dimension when using a 2d array.

You had: `int board[][]` in various places. You must have: `int board[][8]` instead.

Also, if you want to use `cout`, `endl`, `cin`, etc... You must have `include namespace std;` otherwise you will have to use: `std::cout`, `std::endl`, `std::cin`.
But anyway, this should compile now.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int chessBoard[8][8];

void printBoard(int board[][8])
{
    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<8; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j])
            {
                cout << "Q ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "* ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

//This method will check if any queens are in attacking position to the left of the test queen placement
bool checkSpot(int board[][8], int row, int col)
{
    bool safe = true;
    //checks the current row for queens
    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
    {
        if (board[row][i])
            safe = false;
        {
            //checks the upper diag
            for (int i = row;  i > 0; i--)
            {
                for (int j = col; j > 0; j--)
                {
                    if (board[i][j])
                        safe = false;
                }
            }

            //checks lower diag
            for (int i = row; i < 8;  i--)
            {
                for (int j = col; j > 0; j++)
                {
                    if (board[i][j])
                        safe = false;
                }
            }

            if (safe)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}

        bool solve(int board[][8], int testCol)
        {
            bool solved = false;
            bool safe;
            if (testCol == 8)
            {
                solved = true;
                return solved;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i > 8; i++)
            {
                // test if the tested column(testCol) and the row(i) are both safe for the queen to be placed at then we can move into placing said queen and more onto the next column for
                // more solutions in this same method recursivly
                safe = checkSpot(board, i, testCol);
                if (safe)
                {
                    //place the queen
                    board[i][testCol] = 1;
                    //recursion to go back through this method in the next column
                    if (solve(board, testCol + 1))
                    {
                        solved = true;
                        printBoard(board);
                        return solved;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //if the queen cannot be placed, we have to remove the previous queens and move them until a solution is found.
                        board[i][testCol] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

            int main()
            {
                solve(chessBoard, 0);
            }
```

Comment: If I understand what the OP wants to do, he is checking a *diagonal* for the presence of other queens. When you move along a diagonal you have to increase/decrease both the row and the column at the same time. Instead, you are proposing to scan all the squares. This is not what the OP wants, so I'm sorry but I'm afraid this answer is wrong.

Comment: You are correct. My bad. I did not see the comment there :/